# IntelliJで実行ボタンが消えてビルドできない

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJを用いてJavaのコード開発を行おうとしているのですが、「◯◯をプロジェクトフォルダーから削除しますか」というダイヤログにOKを押したところ、実行ボタンやデバッグボタンなどがグレーアウトされ実行できなくなりました。カーソルを持っていくと「エディターのファイルが実行可能ではありません。」という表示です。

なお、開いていたプロジェクトだけではなく、他のプロジェクトでも実行ができなくなりました。
初歩的な内容で恐縮ですが、こちら、原因と対処方法をお分かりの方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示頂けますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「○○」が肝腎だと思いますがよく見ないでOKを押すことはありがちかも知れません。そのダイアログが表示される前に何をしていたのか、どういう操作をしたら表示されたのか、あやふやでもいいので何でも思い出して追記してみるのがいいでしょう。ちなみに状況から考えて最悪IntelliJの再インストールになるかも知れません。ソース等が残っていればプロジェクトは再構築可能なので時間がもったいなければそういう手段もありますよ。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。pom.xmlをmavenプロジェクトに追加するとしてみたところ、認識されるようになりました。